# Polymer auto-register method on platinum-sw-register element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, service-worker

I have installed the getting started polymer app (yo polymer).

And I am setting the auto-register to false on the platinum-sw-register element.

As I am not calling the elements register method I do not expect the service worker to be registered. But in chrome dev tools I can see service worker which seems to be activated and running even after deleting it and refreshing the page.

Am I misunderstanding what this property is used for? I was expecting not to see the service worker in the chrome dev tools until I manually called the register method on the element.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a correct understanding of what that property is for.

I'd recommend using a new Chrome Incognito window when experimenting with service workers (including those registered via `<platinum-sw-register>`). It ensures that you'll start fresh each time.

I just modified a local copy of the [demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-sw/blob/master/demo/index.html) to remove the `document.querySelector('platinum-sw-register').register();` call, and confirmed that in an Incognito window, there's no service worker registration listed under `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`. So the property appears to be behaving as intended.

Comment: Hi Jeff, yes if you remove document.querySelector('platinum-sw-register').register(); everything works as expected.  Leave that removed and add, auto-register="false", to the platinum-sw-register element.

Comment: Attributes in HTML are _falsey_ if they don't exist, and _truthy_ if they do exist, this means `auto-register="false"` is a _truthy_ value.

Comment: Ahh of course. Different from the way angular directive attributes are set, where bool attributes can be set to T/F. e.g. rotate, on Pagination directive in angular UI bootstrap.